# Clang linker error when overloading abstract operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

The VisualStudio 2013 compiler handles the following code just fine, but clang 5.0 and 6.2 gives me a linker error:

```
#include <memory>

using namespace::std;

class IBase
{
public:
    virtual IBase& operator=(const IBase& other) = 0;
};

class Base : virtual public IBase
{
public:
    Base& operator=(const IBase& other) override
    {
        const Base& b = dynamic_cast<const Base&>(other);
        return *this = b;
    }

    virtual Base& operator=(const Base& other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

class IDerived : virtual public IBase
{
};

class Derived : public IDerived, public Base
{
public:
    using Base::operator=;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    shared_ptr<Derived> d1 = make_shared<Derived>();
    shared_ptr<Derived> d2 = make_shared<Derived>();
    *d2 = *d1;
}
```

Here's the build log output:

```
Ld /Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Products/Debug/Oper normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Jennifer/Documents/Operator
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Intermediates/Operator.build/Debug/Oper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Oper.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Intermediates/Operator.build/Debug/Oper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Oper_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Jennifer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Operator-bjjgcoxcziyegjgmazknrandutqz/Build/Products/Debug/Oper

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "IBase::operator=(IBase const&)", referenced from:
      IDerived::operator=(IDerived const&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`IBase::operator=(IBase const&)` is defined in `Base` which `Derived` inherits from, and `Derived` is `using Base::operator=` so it *should* be defined for `Derived`, not overridden by the default assignment operator.

One solution I found was to remove the `IBase::operator=` method, but this is not ideal since it is a method any inheriting class would need to implement.

Does anyone know what the difference is and how to fix it?  I'd like to keep the `IBase::operator=` method if possible.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that a using-declaration does not count as a user-declared assignment operator **[namespace.udecl]**:

> 4 - [...] If an
>   assignment operator brought from a base class into a derived class scope has the signature of a copy/move
>   assignment operator for the derived class (12.8), the using-declaration does not by itself suppress the implicit
>   declaration of the derived class assignment operator [...]

(In any case, `using Base::operator=` gives you an assignment operator with parameter type `Base const&`, which is not one of the parameter types qualifying as a copy assignment operator **[class.copy]**/17 - `T`, `T&`, `T const&`, etc.)

Because `Derived` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator, one is generated automatically, which ends up calling `IDerived::operator=` which calls `IBase::operator=`. Note that automatically-generated copy assignment operators call subobject copy assignment operators ignoring virtual overrides:

> Each subobject is assigned in the manner
>   appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the subobject is of class type, as if by a call to `operator=` with the subobject as the object expression
>     and the corresponding subobject of `x` as a single function argument (as if by explicit qualification; that
>     is, ignoring any possible virtual overriding functions in more derived classes); [...]

A fix would be to write:

```
    Base& operator=(Derived const& other) { return Base::operator=(other); }
```

Note that MSVC 2015 rejects your code but works with the above fix:

```
main.cpp(36): warning C4250: 'Derived': inherits 'Base::Base::operator =' via dominance
main.cpp(14): note: see declaration of 'Base::operator ='
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class IBase & __thiscall IBase::operator=(class IBase const &)" (??4IBase@@UAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class IDerived & __thiscall IDerived::operator=(class IDerived const &)" (??4IDerived@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph in the answer, it may be worth clarifying that even if the using declaration brought in a declaration with the right parameter type, it still wouldn't suppress the implicit declaration of the copy assignment operator.